# my django looks like can`t recognize the templates

Tags: python, django, templates, pycharm

i am a noob learning python,when i learning the template of django,i met some mistakes;what i am using is pycharm2016.2.3 ,python3.5.2,django1.10.1

here is my dir list:

```
│  db.sqlite3
│  manage.py
├─djangotest
│  │  settings.py
│  │  urls.py
│  │  view.py
│  │  wsgi.py
│  │  __init__.py
│
└─templates
   hello.html
```

the url.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

]
```

the setting.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
    ,
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
```

the hello.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>temtest</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>{{ hello }}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

the view.py:

```
#coding:utf-8
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def hello(request):
    context = {}
    context['hello'] = 'yes i am'
    return render(request,'hello.html',context)
def first_page(request):
    info = 'on yes'
    return HttpResponse(info)
```

when i run and type 127.0.0.1:8000 i can open it successfully,
but when i type 127.0.0.1:8000/hello ,it show me this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Id33r.png)

it seems like that the templates can`t be recognized.
can somebody do me a flavor?
thank you!

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with templates.

Comment: @DanielRoseman isn't the render to reponse the templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a url definition :

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^hello$/', djangotest.hello),
]
```

Comment: after i add the url definition,it show me this:   AttributeError: module 'djangotest' has no attribute 'hello'

Comment: OMG,i got the answer from yours,i shoud add url(r'^hello$',view.hello) ,thanks again!